# How to work with result of Active Record `destroy` in `around_destroy` callback

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have `Product` which has many `product_variants`. And `ProductVariant` has many `document_items`. It is forbidden to destroy `product_variant` if it's `document_items` are not empty. And when I `destroy` product, I want to delete all variants or nothing.

This setup works

```
class Product
  has_many :product_variant, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :product 
end

class ProductVariant
  has_many :document_items, dependent: :restrict_with_error, inverse_of: :product_variant 
end
```

If there is `document_item` binded to `product_variant` of `product`.

```
  pv = product.product_variants.first
  pv.destroy # => false, 
  pv.errors.messages #=> { base: ['Cannot delete variant, because there is dependent document_item'] })

  product.destroy # => false
  product.errors.messages # => []
```

BUT. I would like to add some clarifying errors to `product`.
There are two ways:

1) overwrite `destroy` method:

```
  def destroy
    destroy_result = super
    copy_errors_from_associations if destroy_result == false
    destroy_result
  end
```

which works as expected, but Rubocop says

> Rails/ActiveRecordOverride: Use before_destroy, around_destroy, or after_destroy callbacks instead of overriding the Active Record method destroy.

2) using `around_destroy`:

```
around_destroy :propagate_errors_from_associations_on_failed_destroy

def propagate_errors_from_associations_on_failed_destroy
  destroy_result = yield
  copy_errors_from_associations if destroy_result == false
end
```

Which copy no error. It seems that run of `propagate_errors_from_associations_on_failed_destroy` return immediately on first line, if `yield` returns false (actual deletion is aborted)

So I would like to know how I should setup the `around_destroy` callback to check result of `destroy` and if it is false, do something with errors.

Answer (score 2):

`yield` does not returns false when deleting failed. It throws `ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed` exception.

Rescuing from exception should work.

```rb
def propagate_errors_from_associations_on_failed_destroy
  yield
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed => e
  copy_errors_from_associations
  raise e
end
```